# SAP Web Service throwing "Error during access to the ref node"

Tags: web-services, abap, sap-basis

Using transaction code **SRT_UTIL** a web service call is reporting :

Error during access to the ref node 'ITEM'. The ref node is not defined or does not have the necessary type

ITEM is the name of a structure in the call.

Additionally it says the error type is CX_ST_REF_ACCESS and provides the following:

```
<ERROR_CATEGORY>XML-Conversion</ERROR_CATEGORY>
<T100_AREA>SRT_CORE</T100_AREA>
<T100_MSGNO>143</T100_MSGNO>
```

I'm able to communicate with other SAP web services (in the same interface and in others) without an issue. Using both VB .NET and PHP (using wsdl2phpgenerator).

Comment: If you have the access to the SAP system, why don't you test it directly in the system with SPROXY?

Comment: Honestly, I didn't even know that was an option... I'll do some research on that transaction and see if it gets me any closer to resolving this.

Comment: @Jagger thanks for the idea, but the error message from that wasn't much better (but I learned some new tricks). After bouncing the problem back and forth with the ABAP team they think it might be the length of the structure name in SAP. It's 30 characters in SAP and 26 in the WSDL (sans the underscores). In initial testing it appears that shortening the name might solve the issue. I'll know more tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm certain there are other reasons this error may appear, but in this case it turned out the BAPI structure name was 30 characters, which translated to 26 characters in the WSDL (sans the underscores). Decreasing the length of the names by 10 characters has resolved the issue.